# php: catch PDO exception and continue execution?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exception

My project using PDO exceptional handling in 'db.class.php' which is global file for all libraries which can't be changed due to impact.

In some point of time, application is trying to connect a new database and if  new database is not accessible then script should ignore this error  and continue the execution.

New DB connection exception is handled in 'db.class.php' and when I am trying to handle the exception while connecting a new database, somehow  exception handling not working and script is stopped  at that point.

If I am not handling  exception while connecting to new DB, in this case also script stopped executing.

Requirement is even if DB is not connecting in this case due to any issue, script should continue the execution ignoring the error.

**Code:**

```
try {   
        $newDb = new DB(DB_HOST_new, DB_NAME_new, DB_USER_new, DB_PASS_new, DB_UTC_TIMEZONE);
        $isDbSsConnected = true ;
    } catch (PDOException $exx)  {          
        //throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }
```

**db.class.php**

```
try {
            $connection = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
            $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            if ( $utc ) {
                $this->setUtc( $connection );
            }

            $this->connection = $connection;
            self::$connections[$dsn][$username] = self::$connectionCachingEnabled ? $this->connection : NULL;

        } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
            throw new DbEx( "Initialize Failed: DSN = " . $dsn, DbEx::INIT_FAILED, $ex );
        }
```

Comment: Are you within a namespace? Try `\PDOException` within the catch.

Comment: No, its not within a namespace..

Comment: how about cache the generic exception?
catch (Exception $e) {
  // Do stuff
}

Comment: Tried generic Exception handling also but strangely its also not working...

Answer (score 1):

The `db.class.php` file is throwing a `DbEX` exception which is probably the one you should be catching, not the generic `PDOException`.

Comment: I tried but even this also not working ...   catch (DbEX $exx)  {
         
         //throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
         
        }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your custom exception name DbEx

```
/**
 * Define a custom exception class
 */
class DbEx extends Exception
{
}
```

Then you have DB class

```
class DB
{
    public function __construct($host, $name, $username, $password, $timezone)
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name";
        $username = $username;
        $password = $password;
        $utc = $timezone;

        try {
            $connection = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
            $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
            throw new DbEx("Initialize Failed: DSN");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a page/file that you will call the connection from class DB

```
try {   
    $newDb = new DB('localhost', 'test', 'root', '', true);
    $isDbSsConnected = true ;
} catch (DbEx $exx)  {          
    // catch error from DB class
    echo "script should go here ignoring the error";
}
```

The code above will work as your requirements, however, with your code on this part

```
throw new DbEx( "Initialize Failed: DSN = " . $dsn, DbEx::INIT_FAILED, $ex );
```

I think you need to double check the error message the error might came from this code itself.

Comment: May I see your custom Exception code? "DbEX" and what is the error message?

Comment: If you could also add you class DbEx code on your question it will help.